# Capturing bluetooth button press (Call button) in android or Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to capture bluetooth headset button press event such as call button pressed. I have an app where I want user to accept/decline the incoming call using the bluetooth headset button. The accept / decline button is shown as pending notification intent with action button. I tried several things so far, such as `MediaButton intent filter`, `Voice_Commands`, `VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT`. My broadcast receiver break point hits when bluetooth device get connected or disconnected. But it never get hit when pressing a Bluetooth button.

Here is my sample code:

```
 [Activity(Label = "bleCommands", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    [IntentFilter(
        new[] { "android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND",
                "android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED",
                "android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT",
                "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED",

        },
        Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT", "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" })]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            RegisterReceiver();
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        private void RegisterReceiver()
        {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionMediaButton);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
            var receiver = new BleInterceptorReceiver();

            filter.Priority = 10000; //this line sets receiver priority
            RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
    }
```

Here is my BleInterceptorReceiver class

```
public class BleInterceptorReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var intentAction = intent.Action;
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(intentAction))
                Toast.MakeText(context, intentAction, ToastLength.Long);


            var evt= (KeyEvent) intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent);
            if (evt == null)
                return;

            var action = evt.Action;
            if (action == KeyEventActions.Down)
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Down Button pressed", ToastLength.Long);

            if (action == KeyEventActions.Up)
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Up Button pressed", ToastLength.Long);

        }
    }
```

So any ideas / suggestion on what could be the wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Would this Android official documentation be helpful for you? [Responding to media buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#java).
In addition, the method `GetParcelableExtra` is deprecated on Android API level 33, please refer to [This method was deprecated in API level 33](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Thanks but i tried that earlier but it didn't work as well.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Thanks but it seems like audio needs to keep playing in order to receive the button pressed. In my case, it is not a music app, but a VoIP app and i need to listen / act on call button pressed